# Poor table function performance compared to view

Tags: sql, postgresql

We have a table function (below simplified code below):

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.get_active_locations(at_date_time timestamp with time zone)
 RETURNS TABLE(location_id character varying)
 LANGUAGE sql
AS $function$
select location_id from locations 
where activated_date >= at_date_time 
and (deactivated_date <= at_date_time or deactivated_date is null)
$function$
```

The same code in a view:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW public.active_locations as
select location_id from locations 
where activated_date >= now() 
and (deactivated_date <= now() or deactivated_date is null)
$function$
```

The performance of the view is 20-40x faster when called (joined onto other tables).  I understand this must be due to postgres query analyser optimising the queries for the view but not the function.

Any pointers on what we can do to improve?  We are keen to use the function due to the required parameter

Comment: Could you please share the results from explain(analyze, verbose, buffers) for the different SQL statements (in plain text) and the DDL for the tables and indexes involved? And what version do you use? Functions using SQL, like yours, can be optimized by the planner. NOW() and at_date_time are not the same thing, at_date_time could be unknown when planner the query